# Unity How to read MP4 video metdata and get the video's Major Brand

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to read the metadata that exists in the MP4 video file in order to get the **Major Brand** ( A.K.A **ftyp** ) value that exists in it, but I could not find any existing methods to do so in Unity. So, I would like to know are there any methods/solutions in order to achieve this?

Comment: Unity doesn't have any method to do that. You need platform specific methods depending on the platform your game is for.

Comment: I am doing this for **Android**, do you have any advice or solutions in order to do this?

Comment: Since android has a native way of handling files and reading metadata this is a hard thing to do, the closest thing I found is [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/metadata-inspector-66087) asset but it is only for images...

Comment: Native plugin ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to post the solution as an *answer* to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time wasted, I finally have a solution to retrieve the value of MajorBrand from Mp4 video. I am sharing my solution here, hope it will be able to help other people

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream( filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite );

BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader( fileStream );
binaryReader.BaseStream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
byte[] verifyArray = binaryReader.ReadBytes( 32 );
binaryReader.Close();

ConvertToString( BitConverter.ToString( verifyArray ) );

private void ConvertToString( string hex )
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    string[] splitHex = hex.Split( new char[] { '-' } );
    for (int i = 0; i < splitHex.Length; i++)
    {
       int value = Convert.ToInt32( splitHex[i], 16 );
       string stringValue = char.ConvertFromUtf32( value );
       char charValue = (char)value;
        if( value != 0 )
           builder.Append( stringValue );
     }
 }
```